# How can I replace @MockClass, which was deprecated?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, jmockit

I have code, which is using old version of JMockit library.

```
@MockClass(realClass = SomeClass.class)
public class MockSomeClass {
    public SomeClass it;

    @Mock
    public void $init(DataSource dataSource) {
        Deencapsulation.setField(it, new MockDataSource());
    }
}
```

How should I change `@MockClass` annotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class MockSomeClass extends Mockup<SomeClass>{
    public SomeClass it;

    @Mock
    public void $init(DataSource dataSource) {
        Deencapsulation.setField(it, new MockDataSource());
    }
}
```

Comment: This is going to throw a NPE, since `it` will be `null`.